# Class Diagram: Aggregation or Composition

Tags: uml, aggregation, composition, class-diagram

I'm doing an assignment on class diagram and the following shows the association between classes `Order` and `Menu Item`. Should the link be aggregation (weak) or composition (strong)?

[image]

I'm confused because I've seen example showing aggregation. I felt it should be composition as an `Order` must have at least 1 `Menu Item` added. Am I wrong?

Comment: The mileage of your instructor may vary, but one of my professors once said: "The distinction between aggregation and composition is extremely subtle, ill-defined, and completely subject to personal interpretation. When you draw a UML class diagram, decide to use either aggregation or composition, but do not waste any further thought of it. Whenever you encounter a diagram that includes both, do not assume that the author wanted to express anything specific by the distinction, but rather, that the author accidentally clicked different buttons at different times." *Maybe* this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Should the link be aggregation (weak) or composition (strong)?

It can be both. The main difference is:

In case it's a composition:

- MenuItem objects are instantiated at the instantiation time of the Order object.
- The MenuItem objects are destructed as soon as the Order object is destructed.
- C++ example:

  ```
  class Order {
      MenuItem menus[NUMBER_OF_MENUS];
  };
  ```

In case it's a aggregation:

- The lifetime of the MenuItem objects is independent of the Order object lifetime.
- C++ example:

  ```
  class Order {
      MenuItem* menus[NUMBER_OF_MENUS];
  };
  ```

So it's a design decision. And might also depend on the implementation language. In Java, for example, there is no distinction between both, all object variables are references.

Answer (score 0):

A lot is dependent on context.  Let's use an example that should clarify the difference for you.

Suppose you are assembling a Car object in a car factory.  The Car object has two Axle objects, four Wheel objects, a Motor object, and so on.  All of those objects only have meaning within the context of the entire car (once you put them in, they stay there).  That's composition.

Now, suppose you have a Car object in a junkyard.  The Car object has the same stuff, but you can pull wheels or axles or the motor out of it and sell them separately.  In that case, each part has a lifetime separate from that of the car.  That's aggregation.

Comment: And answer to OP's question (no cars, but orders and menu items) would be?

Comment: Wow.  Answer to question is "a lot is dependent on context."  If you'd like to spell out the different contexts for the OP, go ahead.  I prefer to give an analogous context where the distinction is obvious.  If you find that is pedagogically unsound, please explain why in more detail.  Now, I've gone out of my way to accommodate your prickly and abrasive personality in the past, and I will ask you now to at least make an attempt to refrain from sarcastic, self-important, and/or disrespectful comments in future.  I'm afraid I'm about fed up.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offense aside. OP's question was not only about abstract terms aggregation vs composition which was answered already plenty of times, but about concrete example of `Order` and `Menu Item`. How is your answer more complete and better than that of @sergej?

Comment: Why does it have to be?  It wasn't intended as such, just another way of looking at the same thing.  Sometimes people get things more easily when they are explained more than one way.

Comment: from my point of view you did not answer OP's question. As for the why your question should be better see some discussion in [StackOverflow Meta: What to do if there's a better answer than mine?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256171/what-to-do-if-theres-a-better-answer-than-mine)

Comment: Ok.  The OP was asking whether to use aggregation or composition.  (Agreed?)  sergej's answer primarily focused on how to implement each, saying that whether to use one or the other was a design decision.  Let's start there.  Why, in your point of view, is "it's a design decision" and an example of how to implement each a "better" answer the OP's question than mine?  If it's because, as you assert in your first comment, the OP was asking for a "concrete example of Order and MenuItem", please provide evidence of same in the form of quotes from the OP's post.

Comment: OP: "_association between classes `Order` and `Menu Item`. Should the link be aggregation (weak) or composition (strong)?_". You: "_`Car` object in a car factory_" and "_`Car` object in a junkyard_". Sorry, I don't understand your point, English is not my native language

Comment: I understand English is not your native language, and if I may say so your English is excellent.  If you're having trouble understanding my point, the fault is in my explanation, not in your command of English.  :)  Let's take a step back.  I think we have different ideas about what the OP is asking.  Why do you believe that the OP was asking for a "concrete example of Order and MenuItem"?

Comment: 6 occurrences including picture

Comment: Picture doesn't ask for a concrete example.  I see no occurrences of the OP asking for a concrete example.  Can you give me just one of those?  Conversely, I find at least three examples (including the title) of the OP asking whether she should use composition or aggregation, which is how I understand the question.

Comment: "_association between classes `Order` and `Menu Item`_". Perhaps we're both reading different question. Can you add words `Order` and `Menu Item` to your answer?

Comment: Sure.  The OP shows a diagram, explaining that the diagram shows an association between two classes, Order and Menu Item.  She mentions that it shows them as composition.  She mentions that she has seen her example using aggregation as well, and asks which is correct.  So, which is correct, composition or aggregation?  She guesses that it might be composition, because an Order will always need a Menu Item.  So, where has anyone answered the question of whether to use aggregation or composition?  I've given some hints.  Shall I just tell her?  I'd rather she figured it out...